# Understanding relative humidity

Tags: humidity

I am having some trouble understanding relative humidity. If I have a vacuum chamber in which I place a hygrometer to measure relative humidity. In case I am able to achieve full vacuum, will the theoretical RH drop to 0? There will also be high pressure in the chamber at that point. How will that affect RH?